# Javascript function and this

Tags: javascript, closures

I am learning javascript but I have some doubts about functions/closures, i have this code:

```
var obj = { value: 0 };

obj.test = function() {

    var that = this;

    var f1 = function() {

        console.log(that);
    };

    f1();


};

obj.test();

var x = obj.test;

x();
```

I know that when a function is invoked like  f()  `this` refer to the global object but in my example when f1 is defined it has a reference `that` to the `this` of the outer function that refer to obj. 
I expect that the function remember the context in which it was created so why the last call `x()` refers to the global object?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I expect that the function remember the context in which it was created

That right there is your mistake. JavaScript functions do **not** "remember" any relationship to any particular object in a case like that. The only things they remember are in-scope variables in the chain of parent lexical contexts. In this case, the "obj" variable is such a variable.

You can *explicitly* create a function that remembers a relationship to an object with the `.bind()` method.

```
obj.boundTest = obj.test.bind(obj);

var x = obj.boundTest;
x(); // will do the right thing
```

or even more simply:

```
var x = obj.test.bind(obj);
x();
```

Comment: I like your suggestion of using bind here, it is a good way to maintain a connection back to the context.

Answer (score 2):

> I expect that the function remember the context in which it was created

It doesn't.

Context is determined by how a function is called and only by how a function is called.

You are calling it in the global context, so `this` is the global object.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this occurring is that when you make a copy of that function

```
var x = obj.test;
```

you are *only* copying the function. Not the object, nor any of its variables. So when you attempt to run x (which is obj.test) it runs fresh. The result is that `this` is re-evaluated which now refers to the global context (or undefined in strict mode).